# Spring MVC JSP Parameters

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm looking to turn off try blocks for a specific JSP page (though turning it off globally would be OK as well). From what I've gathered, it looks something like this:

```
<jsp-param>
<param-name>noTryBlocks</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</jsp-param>
```

However, everywhere I see that sample it's for a weblogic.xml file. Does anybody know how I can set this JSP parameters for a Spring MVC application? web.xml? Perhaps somewhere near here?:

```
  <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
  </bean>
```

Comment: Spring doesn't do anything magical with JSPs. Why can't you keep using `noTryBlocks` like you already do? Have you tried it?

Comment: Forgot to mention, the deploy environment is glassfish. I don't have a weblogic.xml. I don't know where to put noTryBlocks in the first place. It seems to be a JSP parameters, so my thought was that the spring config for JSP's might have a way to set the parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`noTryBlocks` is a Weblogic-specific feature (that's why it's in `weblogic.xml`). In fact, a web search suggests it was removed in Weblogic 9+.

From what I can tell, the only useful purpose of this is to slightly reduce the size of the compiled JSP. This sounds like a nasty hack to begin with; if this is the case, and you would be better served by making your JSPs smaller to start with (using includes or tag files).

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to include a large file in a JSP per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349818/spring-webcontent-resources-access-outside-servletcontext . Found a way to do it via a streaming file servlet instead, making the JSP include tag (and noTryBlocks) unneeded.